# Display loading/processing while processing using CSOM

Tags: sharepoint-online, client-object-model, jquery

My current implementation includes following,

User adds an item, once saved it is redirected to the display form of the same item. I have implemented this requirement using below steps.

1. On PreSaveAction() redirect to an intermediate form by passing some values using querystring.
2. On intermediate page i use CSOM to retrieve the ID of latest saved item and again redirect to the Actual item

Now this takes some time while processing and i want to show loading status using jquery or any sharepoint based solution.

Something like this would be great :

[image]

Can anybody please suggest me how can i do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use SP.UI.ModalDialog.showWaitScreenWithNoClose If you want to use the 'Waiting' dialog

```
function OpenDialog(targetUrl) {
    var waitScreen = SP.UI.ModalDialog.showWaitScreenWithNoClose("Loading", "Please wait");
    var options = SP.UI.$create_DialogOptions();        
    options.url = targetUrl;        
    options.autoSize = true;
    options.allowMaximize = false;
    options.allowClose = true;
    options.args = waitScreen; //pass the reference of the wait screen to the dialog

    SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);        
}



$(document).ready(function(){
   var waitScreen = SP.UI.ModalDialog.get_childDialog().get_args();
   waitScreen.close();
});
```

follow this http://blog.collabware.com/2013/03/22/tips-tricks-sharepoint-2013-modal-dialogs/

Comment: this link is broken

Answer (score -2):

use this enough
        $.ShowProcessing("Refreshing Collections...");

Comment: There is no `ShowProcessing`method on `$` by default